# @react-native-community/datetimepicker install throwing error

Tags: react-native, expo, datetimepicker

I tried to install datetime picker for my react-native (expo) project but, when i try to install it;

```
expo install @react-native-community/picker
```

It throws error;

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react@16.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.3" from @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/datetimepicker@"3.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-native)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-native-windows@0.64.12
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-windows
npm ERR!   peer react-native-windows@">=0.62" from @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/datetimepicker@"3.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\irfan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\irfan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-30T13_38_37_968Z-debug.log
```

As per this error (if i got it right), this requires a different version of react (17.0.1) which when installed solves the problem but this version of the react is not supported by expo.

Please provide a solution which will be compatible with expo.

Comment: I have `"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2"` and `"react": "16.13.1"` installed, and it works totally fine.

Comment: Same react version but not installing. BTW i found a solution now. Adding as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a whole day, i thought to post it here. But just after posting, i got an answer in my mind.

Why not to clone it directly from the github instead of installing it with `expo` or `npm`.

Did the same thing and now working fine.

This issue was also raised on github but it had no solutions.